# Is it ok to ask questions here which can be found easily by searching on Google?

Tags: discussion, acceptable-question, asking-questions

I am just curious how the community feels about the questions on Security StackExchange that can be answered by searching on Google?

Comment: There is already a question about this on [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191653/should-i-ask-a-question-that-is-easily-google-able). The questions linked in that question state that it is ok to ask easily googlable questions, the answers to the question however state that it may not always be a good idea. My experience at security.SE is that such questions are not well recieved by the community. Personally, I think that the fact that an answer is easily googlable doesn't make them bad questions (although they still may be bad for other reasons)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If it's the sort of thing that pops out as the first result when you do a google search using the exact terms in the question, and the answer describes exactly what is needed, then we aren't exactly adding any value.

Basically, we do expect you to do some basic research before asking the question. A Wikipedia article with the same name as the subject of the question should clearly have been reviewed first.

For many supposedly simple questions, though, there may be intricacies, gotchas, or additional information required to give a full answer. These are absolutely within our remit.

Comment: Also, lots of info on Google is far from authoritative. It takes some level of expertise to weed out the junk. Stackexchange gets the experts to look into your questions and tackle it from many points of view. But yes, a very straightforward question should not belong here.

Answer (score 2):

I personally believe, that if it hasn't been answered before on Stackexchange, it should be a valid question.

Especially considering that

> it can be found on Google

is basically the same as

> here, this link is the answer

which breaks once the website changes something.